# AlarmManager not always executing

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an android app that sends every 5 minutes a post to a server so this way, the server can check if the phone has or not connection.

I'm using `AlarmManager`, sending a broadcast `PendingIntent` to a `BroadcastReceiver` which sends a post to a server. The issue is that it is not always executing:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Inicio.this, NetworkStatusReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Inicio.this,
                                                         0,
                                                         myIntent,
                                                         0);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int interval = 60000*5;
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                     System.currentTimeMillis(),
                     interval,
                     pendingIntent);
```

Is the `AlarmManager` class the right way to do this?

Because I've been researching about 5.0+ android versions and the power management is different from the earlier android versions. Maybe the `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` option is not working on 5.0+ android versions.

Comment: Is it happened in any specific phone ?

Comment: @Saveen The app is used on different devices whith different android versions. Mostly 5.0.2 or 6.+ (there are some old devices which run 4.+, with those ones, there seems to work right!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some research and I've found something that seems to work. Since this morning, I implemented it and the behavior has improved very much. I realized that having a `BroadcastReceiver` I could just set the alarm once and set another alarm again on the `BroadcastReceiver` itself when the alarm was being triggered.

I also used the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`for the `PendingIntent`(since the alarm `PendingIntent` can be triggered from different activities)

The code for the `Activity` would be something like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NetworkStatusReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    final AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

And the code for the `BroadcastReceiver.OnReceive()` method would be the same code so the alarm triggers every `System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInMillis` again (creating this way the `setRepeating()` method)

This way it seems that the alarm is always triggered since (I think) `set()` method from `AlarmManager` works fine with any android version.